# Can I make a wire splice in my main panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, splices

While installing an Eaton CHSPT2Ultra surge protector to panel I cut the wire to beaker too short. Can I splice the cut wire back on?

Comment: In general you can splice wires in a breaker panel.  How short did you cut it and why?

Comment: I measured wire to existing beaker in box that was wider than 50 amp breaker I was connecting to.

Comment: I would give myself enough wire to play with.  It is harder to work with very short wire than one that is at least a few inches long.

Comment: You question has answers elsewhere, but FYI, I like to leave every wire in the panel long enough to reach anywhere in the panel, with at least a few inches extra for errors.  It does make the panel a little messier, but I aim for future adaptability and ease of maintenance.    There are those who violently disagree with this approach and like to use calibrated rods to bend all the wires to exact radius and post pictures of their museum-quality finish on Facebook.  That's valid, but I bet you're not doing that. :)